# Why is the Raspberry Pi Camera Shutter Speed Limited to 2 Seconds

Tags: camera

I have been doing a lot of coding for the Raspberry Pi Camera in Python and have stumbled across a problem. To change the shutter speed of the camera in Python, it is possible to use this attribute:

```
  shutter_speed = time in nanoseconds
```

The issue is the shutter speed is limited to 2 seconds according to this article:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=61445

Is there any way round this? And is there a command I can use in Python that uses seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32397/how-to-increase-the-camera-exposure-time

Comment: @exantas that person was looking to get the brightest image possible in a dark environment. From the answer I posted you will see I mention the shutter speed is limited to 2 seconds. This question is about how to increase the shutter speed beyond 2 seconds.

Comment: The camera's exposure is currently limited to 6s rather than 2 (see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=85856). However, shutter speed is limited by framerate so you have to set a framerate of 1/6fps in order to bump shutter speed to 6s. See http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#capturing-in-low-light for a recipe